# 'Bus cycles' unavailable

Tags: boot, dual-boot, cpu

Sometimes when I am booting I stuck on this... [image: booting] And nothing happens. I have windows in dual boot and it doesn't boot either. Now I booted when I pressed and hold power button but not as long as I want to shutdown it. It jumped into recovery mode and I booted. But I would like to fix this bug. Any help?